# How to set IsEnabled to true when binding property is false

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I have two page elements (in the same view) with one dependent on the other. I need my entry to be enabled only if the checkbox is NOT selected. Can I do this without creating another property?

```
<Label Text="Simulate" />
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Simulate}"/>

<Label Text="Route Path"/>
<Entry Text="{Binding RoutePath}" IsEnabled="{Binding Simulate}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a value converter like [InvertedBoolConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/converters/invertedboolconverter) from xamarin community toolkit package:

```
xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"

<Entry Text="{Binding RoutePath}"
       IsEnabled="{Binding Simulate, Converter={xct:InvertedBoolConverter}}"/>
```